# python making a live output of cpu usage

Tags: python, psutil

So I would like to make a python program that displays the computers cpu usage in real time. So far I am using the psutil module to find cpu usage but I'm not sure how to represent the output visualy.

```
import psutil
x=(2)
while x>0:
    cpu = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1, percpu=False)
    print(cpu)
```

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how i could display the results.

Comment: Maybe https://wiki.python.org/moin/Pyjamas. Haven't tested it tho.

Answer (score 0):

tkinter is a simple gui package that comes bundled with python. You could use that.

Or you could `sys.stdout.write`  to print the result without a `\n` every second or so, with `\r` at the beginning to bring the character cursor to the beginning of the line. This would make a refreshing single line terminal display.